# Sharing internet from PC (reverse-tethering) with hotspot mode

Tags: wifi-hotspot, reverse-tether

I have a HTC One V which runs the default HTC-supplied Android 4.0, not rooted. I occasionally come across situations where I've got a dialup (or non-GSM mobile internet) or other non-wireless network and wireless would be *really* useful.

Can I connect my phone to a computer on the internet through USB with USB passthrough - [which is supported](http://www.htc.com/help/in/howto_iframe.aspx?id=167187&type=1&p_id=439), then share that through [hotspot mode](http://www.htc.com/help/in/howto_iframe.aspx?id=167202&type=1&p_id=439)?